# Chernoff bound proof using Markov

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality

Does anyone familiar with the following format of Chernoff bound:

$$
Pr\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \gt T\right ) \le \inf_{\gamma \gt 0}{\left (  \frac{E[e^{\gamma X_i}]}{e^{\gamma T}} \right )}^n,
$$

where $X_i$ are i.i.d.
How can this format be evaluated from Markov bound?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using $x > y$ if and only if $e^{n \gamma x} > e^{n \gamma y}$ for positive $\gamma$ for (1), the Markov inequality for (2), independence of the $X_i$ for (3) and identical distributions for (4), you get
$$\begin{align} \forall \gamma > 0: \qquad Pr\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i \gt T\right ) &\stackrel{(1)}{=} Pr\left(\exp\left(\gamma\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right) \gt \exp\left(n\gamma T\right)\right ) \\ 
&\stackrel{(2)}{\leq} \frac{E\left[\exp\left(\gamma\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)\right]}{e^{n\gamma T}} \\
&\stackrel{(3)}{=} \frac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n E\left[\exp\left(\gamma X_i\right)\right]}{(e^{\gamma T})^n} \\
&\stackrel{(4)}{=} \frac{E\left[\exp\left(\gamma X_i\right)\right]^n}{(e^{\gamma T})^n} \end{align}$$
Then we can pull out the $n$th power, and take the infimum of $\gamma > 0$ to get the result.

Comment: Why can we simply take the infimum? Why can't we have a discontinuity at 0 (for which we haven't shown the inequality) that ruins our fun?

Comment: @Discrete lizard: We know these bounds hold for all positive gamma. The infimum does not cover the case gamma = 0, so any discontinuity there will not affect the value of the infimum.

Comment: yes I realized that only the limit to 0 matters, not zero itself. So as it holds for all strictly positive gamma, the limit is also fine. Thanks for the explanation, though.